# Show that log $Fib_{n}$ is $\theta(n)$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

I need to show log $Fib_{n}$ is $\theta(n)$
by the Fibonacci numbers defined as

$$ F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$ 
for 
$$ n \geq 2 $$
$ F_{0} = 0 $ and $ F_{1} = 1 $

I'm not sure how to approach this.

I can see it grows exponentially as I've shown a basecase for $F_{6}$.

**Basecase for $F_{6}$:**

$$ F_{2} = F_{1} + F_{0} = 1 + 0 $$
$$ F_{3} = F_{2} + F_{1} = 1 + 1 $$
$$ F_{4} = F_{3} + F_{2} = 2 + 1 $$
$$ F_{5} = F_{4} + F_{3} = 3 + 2 $$
$$ F_{6} = F_{5} + F_{4} = 5 + 3 $$

But how I prove it's true for log $Fib_{n}$ is $\theta(n)$
I don't know. Hope someone can help!

Comment: Hint: try to find upper and lower bounds on $F_n$.

Comment: Also - if you consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number you will see there is a closed form expression (for the $n$th Fibonacci number) that is pretty helpful... But that might be overkill! @Cain's answer is probably what you want

Comment: By $\theta(n)$ do you mean [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?

Comment: @rtybase fwiw I assumed that jubibanna meant $\Theta (n)$ (as on the Wikipedia page that you linked to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $F_n$ is an increasing sequence.
This is a simple consequence of the recurrence relation and the fact that $F_0, F_1 \geq 0$.

Now, using this, we have
$$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} \leq 2F_{n-1}.$$
It is straightforward to verify that the solution to the recurrence, $a_n = 2a_{n-1}, a_1 = 1$, is $a_n = 2^n$, which implies $F_n \leq 2^n$.

On the other side, we also have
$$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} \geq 2F_{n-2}.$$
Using similar arguments to the previous case we get $F_n \geq  (\sqrt{2})^n$.

Putting everything together, 
$$\frac{n}{2}\log(2) = n\log(\sqrt{2}) \leq \log(F_n) \leq n\log(2).$$

In other words, $F_n  = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: THANK YOU, Cain! From all the post this is the only one that made sense to me.

Comment: @Cain: (Asking on behalf of [@ Emanual](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/749698/emanual), who doesn't have enough reputation to comment...) How can you tell that $F_n\geq(\sqrt{2})^n$? $F_0=0$ is not greather than $(\sqrt{2})^0=1$; $F_1=1$ is not greater than $(\sqrt{2})^1=\sqrt{2}$; $F(2)=1$ is not greater than $(\sqrt{2})^2=2$; $\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0} F_n x^n = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$$
has a simple pole at $x=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and a simple pole at $x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. It follows that the radius of convergence of the previous power series is $\rho=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\log F_n}{n}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. See [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way to understand this? I've been struggling all evening with this. It's my first months at Data Science :(

Comment: The solutions of recurrences of the form $A_{n+2} = H A_{n+1} + K A_n$ with $H,K\geq 1$ all have an exponential behaviour. This is more or less equivalent to the fundamental theorem of Algebra. Although to know the *definition* of *radius of convergence* and the basic properties of meromorphic functions is pretty useful.