# Log Fibonacci = Theta

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to prove that $\log F_n =  Θ(n)$ and where

$$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$$
$F_1 = 1$, $F_0 = 0$

There's already a [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972748/log-fibonacci-equals-to-theta) about this question, but the accepted answer doesn't explain a certain calculation in detail, and I was hoping someone here understands and could explain it to me!

I don't understand the part

$$\log F_{n+1}=\log(F_n+F_{n-1})=\log F_n+\log\left(1+{F_{n-1}\over
F_n}\right)$$

More precisely I don't understand how $log(F_{n-1}) = \log\left(1+{F_{n-1}\over
F_n}\right)$

I hope someone can explain how this is possible.

Comment: $\log F_{n-1}\ne \log\left(1+\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}\right)$. That would implicate that $\log(a+b)=\log a+\log b$, which is just silly.

Comment: You already asked this question this week https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971350/show-that-log-fib-n-is-thetan, what's the reason for asking it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$, and $\ln (x\cdot y)=\ln x+\ln y$, $$\ln F_{n+1}=\ln(F_n+F_{n-1})=\ln(F_n\cdot(1+\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}))=\ln F_n+\ln(1+\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}).$$

Comment: Wow thanks J.G.! This was exactly what I needed in order to understand the math behind the induction step! Greatly appreciated <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\ln(F_n+F_{n-1})=\ln F_n+\ln\left(1+{F_{n-1}\over
F_n}\right)&\impliedby \small\exp(\ln(F_n+F_{n-1}))=\exp(\ln F_n)\cdot\exp\left(\ln\left(1+{F_{n-1}\over
F_n}\right)\right)\\&\impliedby F_n+F_{n-1}=F_n\cdot\left(1+{F_{n-1}\over
F_n}\right)\\&\impliedby F_n+F_{n-1}=F_n+\require{cancel}\cancel{F_n}\frac{F_{n-1}}{\cancel{F_n}}\end{align}