# More about $\log(Fib(n))$ element of $\theta(n)$, as seen in these previous posts...

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

To demonstrate that this result below is true, but for all logarithm base greater than 1, can we just say that 'Logarithms in different bases differ only by a constant multiplier' ?

$$\frac{n}{2}\log(2) = n\log(\sqrt{2}) \leq \log(F_n) \leq n\log(2).$$

Thanks

Previous posts:
[Show that log $Fib_{n}$ is $\theta(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971350/show-that-log-fib-n-is-thetan?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Log Fibonacci Equals to Theta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972748/log-fibonacci-equals-to-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Log Fibonacci = Theta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973128/log-fibonacci-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: What you want to prove, $\log F_n=\theta(n)$, is that $\log F_n \in [an,bn]$. It follows from $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2},F_n\ge F_{n-1}$, $F_n\le 2F_{n-1}\le 2^n F_1, F_n\ge 2 F_{n-2}\ge 2^{n/2-1}F_1$.

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971350/show-that-log-fib-n-is-thetan?noredirect=1&lq=1, Cain told something that I think is not true at all... $$F_n \geq  (\sqrt{2})^n$$
As I can see:
F(0)=0 is not greater nor equal than $$(\sqrt{2})^0 = 1$$
F(1)=1 is not greater or equal  than $$(\sqrt{2})^1 = (\sqrt{2})$$
F(2)=1 is not greater nor equal than $$(\sqrt{2})^2 = 2$$
...

Comment: @reuns: I don't really understand the last part:  $$ F_n\le 2F_{n-1}\le 2^n F_1, F_n\ge 2 F_{n-2}\ge 2^{n/2-1}F_1$$